# Frame Switch to click on a Box (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, click, box

I have a problem trying to automate my browser with Selenium on Python. It's been several hours that I block, and since I'm a beginner .. :(

I explain my problem:
I have to reach click on a box of Recaptcha. To do this, my bot must click on a button on the site, which then displays the recaptcha that I have to validate. 
Here are the source page screenshot:

[The popup of the recaptcha, in which the checkbox is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s5Ub.png)

[The location of the checkbox that I have to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBVIU.png)

I try this code:

```
time.sleep(5)
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("CaptchaPopup"))
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
CheckBox = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        browser.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-anchor').click())


time.sleep(0.7)  
CheckBox.click()
```

But the latter returns me an error :(

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame
```

I use Python 2.7. 
Do you have a solution ?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you get exception on `browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("CaptchaPopup"))` or `browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))`?

Comment: For browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("Ca‌​ptchaPopup")) i know :/ http://prntscr.com/fth7vq

Comment: Are you sure that there is an `iframe` with such `name`? I see no such attribute on provided piece of `HTML`

Comment: Indeed, you are right, it is not an iframe (You can see here on this screen [link](http://prntscr.com/fthabd)  ). Unfortunately, if I remove this line, I always perceive a mistake:
Selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method": "id", "selector": "recaptcha-anchor"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code to handle required check-box:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "google.com/recaptcha")]')))
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'recaptcha-anchor'))).click()
```

Comment: Oh .. Everything works perfectly! Thank you, it's been so long that I'm looking for a solution ... Thank you! I will study your code further, but I understand what was wrong now